# trino can not load hbase-connector plugin in its docker

Tags: docker, plugins, hbase, trino

I am trying to use trino with its docker and try to add a plugin to it with the code below

```
ARG JAR_FILE

COPY ${JAR_FILE} /usr/lib/trino/plugin/hbase/prestosql-hbase-338-ops-0.1.6.jar
```

the plugin code is from https://github.com/analysys/presto-hbase-connector

I change all presto libs and packages to trino I also change the META-INF.service to the:

```
io.trino.spi.Plugin
```

which contains the address to the class which provide and implement the io.trino.spi.Plugin contains:

```
@Override
public Iterable<ConnectorFactory> getConnectorFactories() {
    return ImmutableList.of(new HBaseConnectorFactory());
}
```

https://github.com/smmalekabadi/presto-hbase-connector forked project is available here

still I get the following error when I run the docker image:

```
2021-01-25T06:30:38.970Z    ERROR   main    io.trino.server.Server  No service providers of type io.trino.spi.Plugin
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No service providers of type io.trino.spi.Plugin
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:589)
    at io.trino.server.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:166)
    at io.trino.server.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:157)
    at io.trino.server.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:138)
    at io.trino.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:117)
    at io.trino.server.Server.lambda$start$0(Server.java:73)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_351____20210125_063014_1.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.trino.server.Server.start(Server.java:73)
    at io.trino.server.TrinoServer.main(TrinoServer.java:38)
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you create a fork of the original connector project and push your changes to your fork? It sounds like you updated everything correctly, but there’s probably a typo or other minor issue, that we can see from looking at the code.

Comment: I also suggest joining the Trino Slack: https://trino.io/slack.html

Comment: sure I will fork it on the GitHub and inform you as soon as possible

Comment: https://github.com/smmalekabadi/presto-hbase-connector you can find my fork here @DavidPhillips

Comment: https://github.com/analysys/presto-hbase-connector/compare/master...smmalekabadi:master#diff-9c5fb3d1b7e3b0f54bc5c4182965c4fe1f9023d449017cece3005d3f90e8e4d8R16 Try changing this to trino as you have renamed all packages.